# switching between vscode editor tabs using python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of the screen while one vscode tab is open(for example on the screen there is a text file) and when I'm done, I want to switch to a different tab and take screenshot of the screen. How can I switch between vscode editor tabs using python code if possible?

Comment: You should know that creating screenshots of text is one of the sore spots of many SO users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vscode, we can use :

1. Alt + number
2. Ctrl + Tab

to switch to different tabs. When running the following code, *Ctrl* key will keep pressed until finish, and using *Tab* and *Enter* key, we can switch to different tabs.

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
import time

k = PyKeyboard()
num = 5 # num of tabs
k.press_key(k.control_key)
for i in range(num):
    k.tap_key(k.tab_key, n=i+1, interval=1)
    k.tap_key(k.enter_key)
    time.sleep(10)
k.release_key(k.control_key)
```